# Create list of variables based on names of variable

Tags: r

I'm running a loop that creates a large number (n) of dataframes called `df-1` , `df-2`, `df-3` up to `df-n`.

Next, I would like to create a list that contains all these dataframes:

```
listofdf = list(df-1, df-2, df-3, ... df-n)
```

I suppose I need a function that creates a list of all objects whose name contains "df-", this list is then input into the `list()` function. I'm stuck on the first part, though.

**Edit**: Thanks for the comments, as suggested, I found a better solution:

```
finaldata = NULL

for (i in 1:n) {

df <- function(xyz)
rbind(finaldata, df)

}
```

My intention was to bind a list of dataframes together to `finaldata` in a separate step, but with this solution I don't need a list in the first place.

Comment: First step, don't create those initial dataframes, immediately place them in a list on creation. If you have more information we can help provide a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function already exists, called `mget()`, use `ls()` inside.

```
> mget(ls(pattern='^df\\d+$'))
$df1
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$df2
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$df3
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- data.frame()
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the comment of @mhovd a bit more specific:

```
listofdf <- vector("list", length = n)
names(listofdf) <- paste0("df_", seq_len(n))

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  do something smart that generates df temp
  listofdf[[i]] <- temp
}
```